# node.js on plesk onyx, npm commands are not working via ssh

Tags: node.js, ssh, npm, plesk

I have installed node.js on plesk onyx via the plesk extension manager. I am trying to install the node.js driver for mongodb. This is done via ssh using npm. However, no npm commands are being recognised.

Node.js is working as I have setup a test app successfully.

I am thinking that the way in which plesk installs node.js doesnt seem to allow for ssh npm access?
Can anyone shed any light on this please?

Comment: Did you try to run these commands from Plesk UI?

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried to use

/opt/plesk/node/6/bin/npm

or

/opt/plesk/node/7/bin/npm

command?

Comment: Thanks IgorG, That worked perfect I was trying /opt/plesk/node/7/lib/node_modules/npm

Comment: having the same problems but your solution doesnt seem to work `npm: command not found`

Comment: After many many hours of scratching my head... this solution has worked for me. Thanks IgorG.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, what i did was  aquick find from ssh command line:

```
find / -name npm
```

Spotted  the right npm in my environment:

```
# find / -name npm
/var/www/vhosts/mibro.help/.nodenv/shims/npm
/opt/plesk/node/12/bin/npm
```

And then use this path to run npm!

Hope this helps.